# Cyclic relations between nodes A>B>C>A

Tags: python

This is how it looks like before and after, for the problem am trying to solve using Python. I have been trying for weeks. And am failing so miserable to tell Python to do the following:

1. **STEP1:** If you find on this document: "LinkedTo=" * (Example value: Node_3)*
2. **STEP2:** Then Stop
3. **STEP3:** Go to the previous NodePosX= and copy the value * (Example value: 10)*
4. **STEP4:** Go to the previous NotePosY= and copy the value * (Example value: 100)*
5. **STEP5:** Then find the next "Node_3" on the document
6. **STEP6:** And replace inside the NodePosX=30 and NodePosY=300 for the copied values 10 and 100
7. **STEP7:** Then look for the next "LinkedTo=" * (Example value: Node_5)* and repeat the STEP2 to STEP5

This is how it looks like **Before** running the Python script:

```
Begin 
    Name="Node_1"
    NodePosX=10
    NodePosY=100
    LinkedTo=Node_3
    LinkedTo=Node_5
End Object
Begin 
    Name="Node_2"
    NodePosX=20
    NodePosY=200
End Object
Begin 
    Name="Node_3"
    NodePosX=30
    NodePosY=300
End Object
Begin 
    Name="Node_4"
    NodePosX=40
    NodePosY=400
End Object
Begin 
    Name="Node_5"
    NodePosX=50
    NodePosY=500
End Object
```

This is how it should look like **AFTER** running the Python script:

```
Begin 
    Name="Node_1"
    NodePosX=10
    NodePosY=100
    LinkedTo=Node_3
    LinkedTo=Node_5
End Object
Begin 
    Name="Node_2"
    NodePosX=20
    NodePosY=200
End Object
Begin 
    Name="Node_3"
    NodePosX=10
    NodePosY=100
End Object
Begin 
    Name="Node_4"
    NodePosX=40
    NodePosY=400
End Object
Begin 
    Name="Node_5"
    NodePosX=10
    NodePosY=100
End Object
```

Do you think am asking to much from Python to do?
Any better suggestions for the title to this problem?

Comment: cross-post on [https://python-forum.io/](https://python-forum.io/Thread-found-%E2%80%9CNode-3%E2%80%9D-and-X1-10-Y1-100-how-to-copyX1Y1-findNext-%E2%80%9CNode-3%E2%80%9D-pasteX2Y2)

Answer (score -1):

I hired a developer and this is the code they wrote

```
'''
By: Alex Reichenbach
'''
import re
begin_regex = re.compile("Begin")
name_regex = "(?<=Name=\"Node_).*(?=\")"
posX_regex = "(?<=NodePosX=).*"
posY_regex = "(?<=NodePosY=).*"
linkedTo_regex = "(?<=LinkedTo=).*"
end_regex = re.compile("End Object")

## Reading the contents of the file
text = open("1-Example-Original.txt", "r").read()
class Node:
def __init__(self):
self.name = ""
self.nodePosX = 0
self.nodePosY = 0
self.linked_to = []

def __str__(self):
linked = ""
for l in self.linked_to:
linked += "\nLinkedTo="+l
return """Begin
Name="%s"
NodePosX=%s
NodePosY=%s%s
End Object
"""%(self.name, self.nodePosX, self.nodePosY, linked)

## Read the text into the node objects
nodes = []
current_node = None
for line in text.split('\n'): ## Iterate through each line
if begin_regex.match(line): ## Begin
current_node = Node()
nodes.append(current_node)
elif re.findall(name_regex, line): ## Name
name = re.findall(name_regex, line)[0]
current_node.name = name
elif re.findall(posX_regex, line): ## PosX
posX = re.findall(posX_regex, line)[0]
current_node.nodePosX = posX
elif re.findall(posY_regex, line): ## PosY
posY = re.findall(posY_regex, line)[0]
current_node.nodePosY = posY
elif re.findall(linkedTo_regex, line): ## LinkedTo
name = re.findall(linkedTo_regex, line)[0]
current_node.linked_to.append(name)

## Copy the linked_to attributes
for i in range(len(nodes)):
for j in range(i, len(nodes)):
node1 = nodes[i]
node2 = nodes[j]
if node2.name in node1.linked_to:
node2.nodePosX = node1.nodePosX
node2.nodePosY = node1.nodePosY

## Print it all out
s = ""
for node in nodes:
s += str(node)
print(s)

## Write to File?
open("_edited.txt", "w").write(s)
```